# Hochschild coboundary on the space of alternative forms

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, noncommutative-geometry, hochschild-cohomology

Assume  that  $A$  is  a  complex  algebra.  By  $C^{n}(A)$  we  mean the  space  of  all  $n-$linear  map $\phi:A^n \to  \mathbb{C}$. An  alternative $k-$ form  is 
 an  element $\phi \in C^{k}(A)$  with  $\phi(a_{\sigma(1))},a_{\sigma(2)},\ldots,a_{\sigma(n)})=sign(\sigma)\phi(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_k)$  for  every  permutation $\sigma$.
The  standard  Hochschild  coboundary $b:C^n(A) \to C^{n+1}(A)$  is defined by $$b\phi(a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_n)=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}{(-1)}^{j}\phi(a_0,a_1,\ldots a_ja_{j+1},\ldots a_n)+{(-1)}^n\phi(a_na_0,a_1,\ldots,a_{n-1}) $$

> Question: Is there  a  unital  complex  algebra  $A$  with the  following  property?:
>
> For  every  alternative $k-$form $\phi: A^k\to \mathbb{C}$,  $b\phi:A^{k+1}\to \mathbb{C}$  is  an alternative $(k+1)-$  form

Comment: Loday's "Cyclic homology" has precise formulas about relationship between the deRham and Hochschild coboundaries

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე  Thank  you  very  much  for  your  interesting  comment. may  I  ask  you  more  explanation:  My  motivation was the  following Consideration of  manifolds  whose  tangent  space are algebra then in place  of  Stokes theorem (With exterior  differential "d', one  think  to  a new  type of Stokes theorem with  consideration of hochschild  coboundary!  May  you  give  a  precise reference  about the relation between de Rham  and  Hochschild  cohomology?Thank you

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე  The  following  conversation says the  integration is  the  only  operator  compatible  to "d". but  we search  some  operation compatible  to "b"    https://mathoverflow.net/questions/255842/an-stokes-type-theorem-for-some-operations-other-than-integral

Comment: Lemma 2.6.5 (in the second edition)

Comment: Here is [another question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/204215/41291) asking practically the same; still, I am hesitant to definitely say it is a duplicate...

Comment: @AliTaghavi: Out of curiosity, what manifolds have a bundle of associative algebras as their tangent bundle? (I assume this is what you mean by "tangent space is an algebra"?) Do you have any references for this kind of stuff?

Comment: @July I don't know whether OP had this in mind but examples of such are [Frobenius manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_manifold)

Comment: @July  as it is pointed out in the above comment and the following answer, Frobenius manifolds are examples of this situation   https://mathoverflow.net/questions/266497/parallel-transport-as-algebra-isomorphism/266498#266498

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე and Ali Taghavi: thank you for the references!